# Catch all VirtualHost not working

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup a VirtualHost that catches all sub domains that don't many any other VirtualHosts. But with this, I keep getting the index.html and it doesn't take me to the error.php page. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and I haven't changed the apache.conf in /etc/apache2. My other VirtualHost is for Nextcloud running at storage.declanmarks.pw.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/main
        ServerName null
        ServerAlias *

        Redirect 404 /error.php
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I not an expert in Apache.

Answer (score 1):

For a catch-all i.e. *default* host you don't need to specify `ServerAlias *`. Just make sure that this is the first `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

If the `VirtualHost` is included from `sites-enabled/`, you could rename it to begin with prefix `000-` or similar, so that it's the first file in alphabetical order. If no other `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` matches, Apache will fall back to the first one.