# Catchall redirect to error page

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

This is a continuation of my other post: [Catch all VirtualHost not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/868811/catch-all-virtualhost-not-working).

I have got the catchall VirtualHost working. But know how do I get it to redirect a custom error page such as 404.

In my VirtualHost I add `Redirect 404 /`, it takes me to the default 404 page. But when I enable `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/index.php` I get the following error

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Below is my catchall config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
    ServerName null

    Redirect 404 /
    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/index.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Duplication of https://serverfault.com/questions/775570/apache-2-4-errordocument-for-multiple-subdomains/999619#999619
See answer https://serverfault.com/a/999619/174375

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `Redirect 404 /` affects even when trying to access `/errors/index.php`.

When giving `404 Not Found`, you don't need to redirect everything to the root. I would suggest giving the human readable error message for non-existing virtual host at `/` i.e. `/index.html` as a normal `200 OK` and use `ErrorDocument 404 /` to give the same content as `404` for all other URLs. The location doesn't need to change when you have already given `404 Not Found`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName null

    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
    ErrorDocument 404 /

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```